# Object word is assign to models automatically in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How object word is added automatically? It makes difficulty in choosing. How to set different words to it?

[image: django admin GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py file add this method at the end

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.field_name
```

> field_name is the field of your model which you want to display

Answer (score 2):

This is the default implementation of the [**`__str__`** method [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) for a Django model. You can implement your own `__str__` method for example:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Musician {self.pk}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Play with def **str**(). Return what you want to see in admin panel. Read about **repr** and **str**. You will get all what is happening here.

```py
def __str__() :
    return "not object" # you can return your variables or methods or expressions here
```

Answer (score 2):

The **str** method in Python represents the class objects as a string – it can be used for classes. The **str** method should be defined in a way that is easy to read and outputs all the members of the class. This method is also used as a debugging tool when the members of a class need to be checked.

The **str** method is called when the following functions are invoked on the object and return a string:

```
    print()
    str()
```

If we have not defined the **str**, then it will call the **repr** method. The **repr** method returns a string that describes the pointer of the object by default (if the programmer does not define it).